# Marathon: Force fetching the resource from App

Tags: marathon

My marathon app definition has a uri array. One of the resource in them will be periodically updated (read replaced). I need to force marathon to fetch URI and replace the resource in sandbox.

From [Marathon Resources Basic](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/application-basics.html#using-resources-in-applications), I understand that marathon uses Mesos fetcher to do the job when app is restarted. However I have read the docs and found no way of doing the same withhout restarting the app.

One way I can think is to replace the resource in the sandbox without relying on Marathon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that you can tell marathon to re-fetch your uri resources periodically without app restart. 
You can run a daemon in your app to fetch the uri resource and extract if needed to mesos sandbox path.

Comment: Yup, that exactly I ended up doing